# Pandas excelwriter; outfile locked and corrupted

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I have the following code:

```
options = {}
options['strings_to_formulas'] = False #Tried to fix 'problem with some content, want to repair' - no succes
options['strings_to_urls'] = False #Tried to fix 'problem with some content, want to repair' - no succes
writer = pandas.ExcelWriter(str(inputfolder) + '/all_results_' + str(sequence_id) + '.xlsx', options=options) 

for file in csv_file_list:
    file_panda = pandas.read_csv(file, sep = '\t', header = None, dtype=str) #dtype=str; Tried to fix 'problem with some content, want to repair' - no succes
    file_panda.to_excel(writer, Path(file).stem, header=False, index=False)

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

But I keep getting the error in excel with that it can't open without repairing some things. The repair log then says `Repaired Records: Worksheet properties from /xl/workbook.xml part (Workbook)`. The only thing I can imagine is that there's quite some cells that start with a '+' or '-', which Excel doesn't like, but googling this problem hasn't helped me so far..

The other problem I keep getting is that when I repair and continue opening the excel file, it keeps saying it's locked for editing by 'another user' and I can only open it as read-only. It seems the file is still 'in use' by my script somehow, even though I closed it and even forced it to release the handles?

Does anybody have any ideas how to solve these problems?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: Thanks, but there's no traceback errors. The code executes perfectly. 
The errors occur when I'm opening excel and they are just the general pop up messages generated by excel when either a file is corrupted (detail of repair log is provided in my post) and when a file is unaccesible because it's opened somewhere else

Comment: I don't know if you should use `writer.save()` because `to_excel()` should already save it.

Answer (score 1):

After trying some more, I found myself that my automatically generated sheet-names based on the file names exceeded the 31 limit Excel puts on it. This causes many problems aparently.